# Saying phone numbers

Tags: prononciation, nombres, oral, téléphone

In the case for phone numbers, how are the digits read? e.g. would

> 96 76 75 99

be read as:

> quatre-vingt-seize soixante-seize soixante-quinze quatre-vingt-dix-neuf

If so, how is it distinguished from:

> 80 16 60 16 60 15 80 19 ?

Comment: I remember an italian friend who was writing down a number that I was saying: _quatre_, he wrote 4, _vingt_, he crossed out the 4 and wrote 8, _seize_, he crossed out the 8 and wrote 96, and laughed.

Comment: If you want to see more about that : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WM1FFhaWj9w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pour information**

Pour la prononciation en français il y a, à ma connaissance, trois styles selon le pays.
En effet, on distingue le français en France, en Belgique et la Suisse.

En France on prononce 70 par soixante-dix et 90 par quatre-vingt-dix.
En Belgique on prononce 70 par septante et 90 par nonante.
En Suisse, et c'est selon moi le plus logique, on prononce 70 par septante, 80 par octante et 90 par nonante.

**Pour ton exemple** donc cela pose problème pour les Français, qui prononceront

- soit chaque numéro (comme en anglais) : neuf/six/sept/six/sept/cinq/neuf/neuf.
- soit en regroupant: neuf cent soixante-sept/six cent soixante-quinze/quatre-vingt-dix-neuf.

En pratiquant bien la langue on fera facilement la distinction quatre-vingt/pause/seize et quatre-vingt-seize sans pause.

Comment: Il me semble que les Suisses disent « huitante » plutôt qu’« octante », qui est vieilli.

Comment: On dit quatre-vingts dans le canton de Genève et huitante dans les canton de Vaud (Lausanne), de Fribourg et le Valais.

Comment: Je suis née et vis en France depuis de très nombreuses dizaines d'années et je n'ai jamais entendu qui que ce soit dire un numéro de téléphone en épelant les chiffres 1 par un. Je ne dis pas que ce n'est pas possible, bien sûr, mais ce n'est pas la coutume. Or la réponse donnée ici met les deux sur un pied d'égalité.// Dans la phrase « soit chaque numéro (comme en anglais) : neuf/six/sept/six/sept/cinq/neuf/neuf. » *neuf/six/sept/six/sept/cinq/neuf/neuf* ne sont pas des numéros mais des chiffres.

Comment: ça pourrait faire partie d'une question à part entière, mais on épelle souvent les chiffres un à un pour les nombres inférieurs à 10. Par exemple 06 76 14 02 00 sera énoncé "0-6-76-14-0-2-0-0"

Comment: @Laure Absolument et les regroupement par trois chiffres sont peu communs également.

Comment: @assylias: mais pas si rares: en Belgique, pour des raisons historiques, certains numéros de téléphones sont groupés et prononcés par 3. Il s'agit des numéros de téléphone pour Bruxelles et ses environs ainsi que pour Anvers et ses environs. Un tel numéro serait, par exemple, 02.456.78.90. Les numéros de GSM (portables) sont groupés encore différemment : 0475.12.34.56. Le 04 n'est pas isolé parce qu'il indiquerait le préfixe de la province de Liège.

Comment: In France for special numbers, the first digits are usually pronounced by group of 3 except the initial zero. For example, 0800 xx yy zz ("zéro huit-cents") or 0812 xx yy zz ("zéro huit-cent-douze"). Also you can say "Les numéros en zéro huit-cents sont gratuits". For the yellow /while pages numbers, they are written and spoken as 2 groups of 3 digits, the first one being 118. For example, 118 218 ("cent-dix-huit deux-cent-dix-huit"). The short EU emergency number 112 is simply spoken "cent-douze".

Answer (score 12):

Essentially, by intonation and pauses. For “80, 16”, one would say:

> Quatre-vingt. [pause] Seize.

with a rising intonation at the end of “80”, whereas for “96”, one would say:

> Quatre-vingt-seize.

in one go, with a rising intonation at the end of “96” (or falling if at the end of a list or sentence).

Comment: Excellent answer. One could add that French has hardly any variation in word and sentence stress and words are nearly always stressed on the last syllable, and intonation falls at the end of a declarative sentence. *96* is one word. *80 16* are two words, therefore French natives do not say them in the same manner.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, phones numbers are usually read this way.

Note that in France, as French numbers have a fixed length, most ambiguities are not possible, except perhaps for numbers like +33 (0)1 73 50 60 15 that could also be +33 (0)1 60 13 50 75. In those cases, and in the context of variable length phone numbers, the intonation, or small pauses between numerals should be enough to disambiguate.